# FFTW3 1D transform with MPI is slow

Tags: mpi, fft, fftw

I'm testing FFTW 1D c2c transform using MPI. 
After compiling and running the 2D example on FFTW3 tutorial I have seen that with 8 nodes execution is 2x faster than using only one node(using large size like 4096x4096).

So I modified this example for 1D but something goes wrong becouse I see this timing :

```
1 node  = 0.763668 s
2 nodes = 1.540884 s
4 nodes = 1.336446 s
8 nodes = 0.851646 s
```

My code :

```
    #include <fftw3-mpi.h>
    # include <stdlib.h>
    # include <stdio.h>
    #include <sys/stat.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>
    # include <time.h>
    #include <math.h>

    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
       //const ptrdiff_t N0 = 4096;
       const ptrdiff_t N0 = 4194304 ;
       //const ptrdiff_t N0 = 8388608;
       fftw_plan planForw,planBack;
       fftw_complex *data,*dataOut,*data2;
       ptrdiff_t alloc_local, local_ni, local_i_start, i, j,local_no, local_o_start;
       int index,size;
       double startwtime, endwtime;
       MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
       fftw_mpi_init();
       MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&index);
       MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);

       /* get local data size and allocate */
       alloc_local = fftw_mpi_local_size_1d(N0, MPI_COMM_WORLD,FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE,
                                                  &local_ni, &local_i_start,&local_no, &local_o_start);
       data = fftw_alloc_complex(alloc_local);
       dataOut = fftw_alloc_complex(alloc_local);
       data2 = fftw_alloc_complex(alloc_local);
             /* create plan  */
       planForw = fftw_mpi_plan_dft_1d(N0, data, data2, MPI_COMM_WORLD,
                                         FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
       planBack = fftw_mpi_plan_dft_1d(N0, data2, dataOut, MPI_COMM_WORLD,
                                         FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
       /* initialize data to some function my_function(x,y) */
       for (i = 0; i < local_ni; ++i) 
       {
        data[i][0] =rand() / (double)RAND_MAX;
        data[i][1] =rand() / (double)RAND_MAX;
       }
       if(index==0){
        startwtime = MPI_Wtime();

        }

        fftw_execute(planForw);
        fftw_execute(planBack);
        if(index==0){
        endwtime = MPI_Wtime();
            printf("wall clock time = %f\n",
                           endwtime-startwtime);


       }

             fftw_destroy_plan(planForw);
         fftw_destroy_plan(planBack);
             MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Comment: 2D and 3D FFTs are performed much more efficiently in parallel than 1D FFT. Multidimensional FFTs are essentially series of independent 1D FFTs in each direction that can be performed in parallel with zero communication. Communication is only involved when data is transposed globally when switching the direction in which the 1D FFTs are performed.

Comment: thank you, but before I try with mpi, I did the same test with FFTW multithreading, and when I using 4 threads (using intel i7 quadcore) with large sizes I have that speed is 2,5x faster than one only thread. Maybe something is wrong in my MPI code ?

Comment: Nothing is wrong. Memory is shared between threads and each of them can access all of the data being transformed. In the MPI case messages have to be exchanged between the different processes at the intermediate steps. This communication overhead leads to the bad performance. You should also put an `MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);` after the data initialisation just to make sure all processes are (approximately) in sync.

Comment: yes , I tried MPI_Barrier too results not change. Do you know the usufulness of the last two parameters of fftw_mpi_local_size_1d (local n out and local out start)? I never used them, and I not know why I could use them..

Comment: The [documentation](http://www.fftw.org/doc/One_002ddimensional-distributions.html) is quite clear on what the last two output arguments are. There are cases when the output array is of different size than the input one (e.g. in a r2c forward transform) and also `local_no` can differ from `local_ni` if the number of data points is not divisible by the square of the number of processes.

Comment: If you are only willing to test forward/backward transforms then you'd better use the "scrambled" data output/input. See _MPI flags_ in [MPI Plan Creation](http://www.fftw.org/doc/MPI-Plan-Creation.html). This will save time by not doing communication to (un-)scramble data.